# Java/Spring library services async

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i have created a java/spring library offering reusable functions like calling an ldap service to check if a user is authenticated to a given directory service.

The library is working and i can integrate it to any given java project via maven or use the api with rest.

I have two questions:

1. I want to call that library service let´s say `public boolean authenticateUser(String login, String password)` asynchronous. Do i code that service within the library asynchronous or should the consuming app do the asynchronous call?
2. Because it is a spring (boot) utilized library i have defined a dedicated `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean within the library. Is this a good idea (a dedicated `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`) or should the consuming app do the defining of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should provide two versions on synchronous and one asynchronous so the client can decide.
2. This should be configurable by the client. So your library must offer to configure the ThreadPool.

Maybe it could be an idea to implement your library as Spring Boot Auto Configuration Starter:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. That Auto Configuration Starter seems to be interesting. I will try that.